# Working with Minishift watchers in Java applications

Tags: java, https, websocket, openshift, minishift

I've been working on a Java application that utilizes the openshift api. Specifically [OpenShift deployment configuration](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.7/rest_api/oapi/v1.DeploymentConfig.html#Get-oapi-v1-watch-namespaces-namespace-deploymentconfigs-name)

I have tried to set up a watcher, but my response body is never called. I am already able to get a response from the 'non watcher' APIcalls. I am using the groovy httpbuilder library to fulfill my request

```
def http = new HTTPBuilder(<<URL TO OPENSHIFT>>)
try {
    http.get(path: '/oapi/v1/watch/namespaces/myproject/deploymentconfigs', contentType: "application/json") { resp, reader ->
        println(resp)
        return reader
    }
} catch (HttpResponseException e) {
    System.out.println(e)
}
```

Please Advise on a path forward to set up OpenShift watchers in my application.
An error message is never thrown. minishift logs -f are not providing any feedback either. 
Also note that I have gotten this to work with the curl command, documented in the api

Answer (score 0):

You can use the OKHttpClient to handle the http websocket upgrade protocol for you. Note legacy versions of minishift require the query parameter "access_token" when trying to make a websocket connection request

```
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        def token = token
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .get()
                .url("https://<<IP>>/oapi/v1/watch/namespaces/<<namespace>>/deploymentconfigs?watch=true&access_token=<<token>>")
                .addHeader("Accept", "application/json")
                .addHeader("Connection", "close")
                .addHeader("Sec-WebSocket-Protocol",'base64url.bearer.authorization.k8s.io.' + Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(token.getBytes()))
                .addHeader('Origin', 'https://<<IP>>')
                .build()
        WebSocketListener websocketListener= new WebSocketListenerImpl()
        client.newWebSocket(request, websocketListener)
```

WebSocketListenerImpl Class

```
import okhttp3.Response;
import okhttp3.WebSocket;
import okhttp3.WebSocketListener;
import okio.ByteString;

public class WebSocketListenerImpl extends WebSocketListener {

    public WebSocketListenerImpl() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public void onOpen(WebSocket webSocket, Response response) {
        super.onOpen(webSocket, response);
        print "WEBSOCKET OPEN"
    }

    @Override
    public void onMessage(WebSocket webSocket, String text) {
        super.onMessage(webSocket, text);
        print "WEBSOCKET RECEIVED"

    }

    @Override
    public void onMessage(WebSocket webSocket, ByteString bytes) {
        super.onMessage(webSocket, bytes);
        print "WEBSOCKET OPEN"

    }

    @Override
    public void onClosing(WebSocket webSocket, int code, String reason) {
        super.onClosing(webSocket, code, reason);
        print "WEBSOCKET CLOSING"

    }

    @Override
    public void onClosed(WebSocket webSocket, int code, String reason) {
        super.onClosed(webSocket, code, reason);
        print "WEBSOCKET CLOSED"

    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(WebSocket webSocket, Throwable t, @javax.annotation.Nullable Response response) {
        super.onFailure(webSocket, t, response);
        println "WEBSOCKET FAILED"

    }
}
```